# Vuejs passing function from parent to child

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a beginner question about passing function from parent to child. In my example, I want to to use the child more times and sometimes it should to do someting else `v-on:focus`. How can i do that? There are options to pass it with prop but i don't know how and i think it's not good to do it ? Maybe with EventBus and if yes then how ? I want to know the right way how to do it in VueJs.

**Here is the Parent Component:**

```
import Child from "./child.js";
export default {
  name: "app",
  components: {
    Child
  },
  template: ` 
              <div>
                <child></child>
                <child></child>
                <child></child>
              </div>
            `
};
```

**And here is the child Component:**

```
export default {
  name: "test",
  template: `
              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
                  <input v-on:focus="functionFromChild">
                  </div>
              </div>
            `,
  methods: {
    functionFromChild() {
      //run the function from parent
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the function as any other prop

```
import Child from "./child.js";
 export default {
  name: "app",
  components: {
   Child
  },
  methods: {
   calledFromChild(id){
     console.log(id)
   }
  },
  template: ` 
          <div>
            <child :callback="calledFromChild" id="1"></child>
            <child :callback="calledFromChild" id="2"></child>
            <child :callback="calledFromChild" id="3"></child>
          </div>
        `
 };
```

And then in the child

```
export default {
 name: "test",
 props: ["callback", "id"],
 template: `
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
              <input v-on:focus="() => this.calledFromChild(this.id)">
              </div>
          </div>
        `,
 }
```

I'm also adding an id to the child so you know which child is making the call.

But this is **not a good idea**. You should use [emit](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Event-Names) from your child to send an event, and [listen](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Listening-to-Events) to it from the parent.

In the child

```
export default {
 name: "test",
 template: `
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
              <input v-on:focus="handleFocus">
              </div>
          </div>
        `,
  methods: {
   handleFocus() {
    this.$emit('focusEvent')
   }
  }
};
```

And in the parent

```
<child @focusEvent="handleFocusFromChild"></child>
```

A working example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-eventbus-try-j1egt)

Comment: I like your second idea with emit, can you make an example with my case?

Comment: I added it at the end of the post

Comment: you don't define it, you just use a string to identify the event. Calling emit('eventName') is enough. If you want to pass data you need to use the second param emit('eventName', payload)

Comment: handleFocusFromChild is declared as a method in parent

Comment: There are a couple of error in your sandbox, a typo regarding methods (you wrote metode) and you need to update to use a predefined method and not an inline one when using inline templates

Comment: I've also updated my answer, and this is a working example https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-eventbus-try-j1egt?file=/child.js

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```js
const Child = {
  template: `
           <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
                  <input v-on:focus="functionFromChild">
                  </div>
              </div>
  `,
  props: {
  functionFromParent: Function
  },
  methods: {
  functionFromChild: function() {
    this.functionFromParent();
  }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      message: 'Oh hai from the component'
    }
  }
}
const App = {
  template: `
    <div>
     <h1>Quick test</h1>
     <p>{{ message }}</p>
     <Child :functionFromParent="functionOnParent"/>
     <Child :functionFromParent="functionOnParent"/>
     <Child :functionFromParent="functionOnParent"/>
    </div>
  `,
  components: {Child},
  methods: {
   functionOnParent: function(){
   console.log("there we go");
   }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      message: 'Hello'
    }
  }
}

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>


<div id="app">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to call a function in the parent from the child component, then try

```
this.$parent.parentMethod()
```

This will invoke the method in parent component.